# Asp Net MVC Membership - Retrieving access rules for Roles. Is there how?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, access-rules

Is there a way to retrieve all access rules from a specific Role?

As roles are just flagged at the top of an action or on top of the whole class I can´t find a way to retrieve this information unless I read and parse the whole file and after that find a way to link this [authorization] tag to a group.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no builtin way. Its even impossible, because you might check for Roles in your code (actions/views) as well.

And how should the list of *access rules* be returned?

For example, how should an algorithm return / name this access rule in a view:

```
@if(User.IsInRole("SomeRole") {
   <div>
       Show some html only visible for users in SomeRole
   </div>
}
```

You have to administer the list of your application defined access rules by yourself - i list will be very specific for your app.

Of cause, when you just use the `Authorize` attribute, you could generate a list of action methods accessible for a given role by reflecting over all controller classes.

Comment: Still confusing because I should have the conf set in web.config. I could do it manually but if I use the asp net configuration tool, the authorization is set but no entry is add to my web.config. Could you help me understand that?

Comment: I don't understand - what entries are you talking about?

Comment: Jan. I have at the top of my actions the tag [authorize]. How the system checks what Roles has the permission to access those actions?

Comment: `[Authorize]` without any paramters means, every authenticated user can access that action. When using parameters you can specify some roles the user has to be in or some usernames.

Comment: I think I found the right question. Using Asp Net Web Site Administration Tool, setting access permission to a controller/actions does not decorates the controlker/action. So do I have to decorate then manually or not? And if it is not nescessary how the system checks those permissions?